# Build a formula that determines the number of stickers per sheet

Tags: algebra-precalculus, area, arithmetic-geometry

I need to build a formula for the following. I have a sheet of cardboard $m$ cm long and $n$ cm wide and inside there are stickers or stamps $p$ cm long and $q$ wide separated by $a$ mm. I need to know the full number of stickers per sheet.

Let's see:
The area of ​​the sheet is $m \cdot n$.
The area of ​​the stickers is $p \cdot q$.

The separation $\frac{a}{10}$ in cm.

I can't find how to put the separation in the formula and 2 cases are presented

a) leave $a$ mm of separation at the edges per sheet

b) do not leave any separation on the edges

can you help me, I hope you understand

edit
the idea is like this but with rectangular stickers

[image]

Comment: Have you drawn a picture?  You can find a rectangle composed of a sticker plus some of the gaps, then see how many of these rectangles fit.  You need to watch out for a fencepost problem.

Comment: I have already made it, but I can't think of it, because the measurements are in letters.

Comment: You said correctly that the area of a sticker is $pq$.  The width of a sticker plus one gap is $p+a$.  If you make a rectangle that is that long and $q$ wide the area is $(p+a)q$.  Don't let the letters scare you.  As I suggested, try to find some gaps that you can add to the stickers to make a rectangle that repeats in each direction.

Comment: hi , Continuing with your analysis and correcting the idea a bit, it would be a stiket area (p+a)(q+a) because there is space on both sides, above and below, so the total will be the integer part of m* n /( p +a)(q+a) Am I okay?  see,edit

Comment: $(p+a)(q+a)$ adds one space on the bottom and one space on one side.  That is what you want to do for the main area because all the space gets accounted for once.  You then need to make a correction at the edge depending on which case you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general formula will be (stickers that fit on the top border) $\times$ (stickers that fit on the left border)

Depending on the case the algebraic form will be different.

Let´s start with case a), the number of stickers that fit on the top border is the integer part of (paper´s width) $\div$ (sticker´s width $+$ gap) however the gap won´t be just a, instead, we need $a + \frac{a}{2}$ because, otherwise, our formula won´t take into account the separation needed between both edges. The number of stickers that fit on the left border is just the integer part of (paper´s height) $\div$ (sticker´s height $+$ gap). So the general formula for case a) is $\lfloor \frac{m}{p+a+\frac{a}{2}}\rfloor \times \lfloor \frac{n}{q + a + \frac{a}{2}}\rfloor = \lfloor \frac{m}{p+\frac{3a}{2}}\rfloor \times \lfloor \frac{n}{q + \frac{3a}{2}}\rfloor = \lfloor \frac{2m}{2p+3a}\rfloor \times \lfloor \frac{2n}{2q + 3a}\rfloor$

Case b) is very similar, however, now the gap we will consider is only $\frac{a}{2}$, so the general formula in this case is $\lfloor \frac{m}{p+\frac{a}{2}}\rfloor \times \lfloor \frac{n}{q+\frac{a}{2}}\rfloor = \lfloor \frac{2m}{2p+a}\rfloor \times \lfloor \frac{2n}{2q+a}\rfloor$

Comment: hi,I don't know why they closed the question, you clarified a lot with your development, a doubt, take note that it is in mm, or where it says divide by 10 to leave it in cm. Thank you

Comment: Yes, you are right, when I use $a$ in the formula I actually mean $\frac{a}{10}$, I am glad it helped you :)